# How to make console run script in the background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I want to block some pop-up stuff, by removing a specific css file.

i use following code

```
$("link:eq(4).[rel=stylesheet]").attr("href", '-');
```

And it works, but if i update the page or click on internal links then i get the pop up again and i have manually type the code in the console again.

Is there a way to automate the process?

Comment: Link tag have a disabled attribute, use it. It will disable all CSS inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set scripts to a page with something like greasemonkey.

https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

Comment: Seems nice i will check right away, but how about chrome? is there one for chrome as well ?

Comment: @NorthernLights Chrome has native support for user scripts :D  

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/24790/beginner-guide-for-greasemonkey-scripts-in-google-chrome/

Comment: cool , btw it did work with greasemonkey. But it very weird that i have to have a alert statement before my orginal line, otherwise it will not work :S ?

Comment: Uhm... it should work without any alert. The page should run the script when it's loaded. Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped :)